# How to delete all documents except one in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building **nodejs application** and I am using **MongoDB official driver(not mongosse)**

And I want to write a command to MongoDB.

```
{"_id": "MAX_ERROR_NODE_SERVERS","what": "conf","serverCount": 10,"added_At": "Sun Oct 09 2022 15:38:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}
```

I have a document like this in MongoDB.

And I want to delete all documents in the collection except the above document.

**That means the above document should not be deleted but all other documents should be deleted in the collection**

What is the command should I write

Comment: Date values should **never** be stored as string, it's a design flaw! Store always proper `Date` objects.

Comment: No it just how I put it here. I add correct data objects to mongodb. What you were staying is to add data like this {_id : "MAX_ERROR_NODE_SERVERS"} to mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `_id` are uniques you can do:

```js
db.yourNameCollection.deleteMany({
  "_id": {$ne: "MAX_ERROR_NODE_SERVERS"}
})
```

Comment: by remove the " " in the "_id" command worked thanks.